# Redirect 301 in .htaccess file, but still the same page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Whats incorrect with this redirect?

```
Redirect 301 /?p=byggnad&id=31 http://domainname.com
```

This works, but then the whole site is redirected. I want to just redirect sime pages on the site.

```
Redirect 301 / http://domainname.com
```

Have I missed something int the fort redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Redirect 301 /?p=byggnad&id=31 http://domainname.com
```

is incorrect and won't work because you cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. You need to use `mod_rewrite` based rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=byggnad&id=31$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainname.com/? [L,R=301]
```

`?` in the end is used to strip off any existing query string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'header'to redirect,code is below.

header("Location: http://domainname.com/?p=byggnad&id=31", true, 301);
exit();

Comment: you can work with                                                     Redirect Redirect /yourolddir/oldfile.extn  http://domainname.com/?p=byggnad&id=31